# How to create a bootable system with a squashfs root

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb, squashfs, kernel

My goal is to be able to take a customized root file system loaded with the software I want.  So far I've created a squashed filesystem using debootstrap and chroot to install the software I want on the system.

The problem I am now running in to.. whenever I boot in to the system, my user accounts that were set up in the chroot do not work.  First boot everything works out, second boot I can't log in.  That is baffling to me.

Any one know a reason or a place to start looking?

Comment: You have to keep searching for the changes you wish to make. Look at the casper scripts and initrd as well as /usr/share and in the libs.

Comment: Well I got it working.  I used the live-boot & live-boot-initramfs-tools to generate an initrd and extlinux for the bootloader.  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get a working system with a squashfs filesystem:

```
sudo apt-get install live-boot live-boot-initramfs-tools extlinux
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Create a squashfs file from a bootstrapped or running ubuntu filesystem with whatever packages you want available.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch provides good instructions for creating a debootstrapped system to build on.  Format the target drive with ext2/3/4 and enable the bootable flag.  Create the folder layout on the target drive and install extlinux:

```
mkdir -p ${TARGET}/boot/extlinux ${TARGET}/live
extlinux -i ${TARGET}/boot/extlinux
dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sdX #X is the drive letter
cp /boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r) ${TARGET}/boot/vmlinuz
cp /boot/initrd.img-$(uname -r) ${TARGET}/boot/initrd
cp filesystem.squashfs ${TARGET}/live
```

Create ${TARGET}/boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf with the following contents:

```
DEFAULT Live
LABEL Live
  KERNEL /boot/vmlinuz
  APPEND initrd=/boot/initrd boot=live toram=filesystem.squashfs
TIMEOUT 10
PROMPT 0
```

Now you should be able to boot from the target drive in to your squashed system.

Answer (score 4):

This question was solved by the OP:

> Well I got it working. I used the live-boot &
>   live-boot-initramfs-tools to generate an initrd and extlinux for the
>   bootloader. Works like a charm.