# Why do we need to create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

To create a USB stick from which you can install Ubuntu, you must first download Ubuntu and then follow http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu.

Why can't we download the http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso to a flash drive, and that's all, and use it for installation?

What does "create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu" actually do?

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't *need* to be done on Ubuntu, there are tools for Windows as well (and OSX too, I think).

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/a/512065/158442

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can: recent Ubuntu ISO images are "hybrid" and meant to be both writable to CD media or directly to a CD. Read here:

https://superuser.com/questions/683210/how-do-i-determine-if-an-iso-is-a-hybrid

If your host operating system is unable to write a raw image to the USB stick without mangling it (I know Ubuntu can do it, using the "dd" command, but I'm unaware if Windows or OS X can) then you need to use a USB creation tool which copies the files from the ISO in a different way and then prepares the stick to be generically bootable.

FWIW, I usually just `sudo dd if=ubuntu-image.iso of=/dev/sdb` (where /dev/sdb is the device for the USB stick) and the resulting stick boots fine.

Answer (score 2):

Ah: some computer archaeology: You need to "create a bootable USB stick" to create the bootable MBR/GPT sectors on your USB stick.  Otherwise all of the information *would* be available on the stick, but the BIOS wouldn't know where to look for it...

BIOS is actually extremely dumb and dates back to the CP/M area where "booting" was: read track 0 and track 1 and show a prompt.  Booting took all of 1 second on a floppy drive...