# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - can't make a bootable USB flash drive

Tags: boot, iso

I'm trying to create a bootable USB drive for 20.04. If I do a 20.04 downloaded image, I can boot the drive properly. However, if I extract all the 20.04 content to a directory, then recreate the ISO and dd that to the drive, the resulting drive won't boot. My zbook just beeps and goes back to the boot menu. The command for creating the ISO I got from several articles.  But I'm certain it has to be the created ISO itself. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you verify the ISO?  (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) but the write instructions are available at https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview   If you provided the `dd` command you wrote it with we may be able to see the issue, but we're limited to what you provide.

Comment: FYI:  It may also help if you're specific as to the ISO of 20.04; there is a bug filed for 20.04.3 for example that I'm currently writing an ISO for to *confirm*, but I'm assuming you're not talking about an *testing* ISO but a released one.  (fyi: the bug only impacts about 3-5% of uEFI boxes; relating to a specific SHIM)

Comment: I am curious to why you're extracting the files from the ISO. Ubuntu ships with an application called "Startup Disk Creator" which does exactly as it promises ...

Comment: You are *not* supposed to "extract" a `*.iso` file, and then copy all the extracted files to a USB. This is not how to create a bootable ISO. All you did was create a USB with a bunch of random files on it. As @matigo suggests, simply use Startup Disk Creator to "flash" the `*.iso` file to the USB. If you *still* want to use `dd`, take a look at [Flashing Ubuntu ISO to USB stick with dd: recommended block size](https://askubuntu.com/q/931581/100356) and [Using 'dd' command to create bootable USB stick](https://askubuntu.com/q/512059/100356).

Comment: @PJ Singh Extracting an ISO file to USB does work, see below. Both Rufus and UNetbootin use that method.

Comment: I think this is the problematic step: "then recreate the ISO". It is far from trivial to create an iso file, that when cloned to a USB drive will make that USB drive bootable. -- Either clone directly from the downloaded iso file (the straight-forward way), or create a partition table with at least one file system (and in case of BIOS boot also create a bootloader), and then extract the content of the iso file to the file system (a more difficult way).

Comment: Do you just want to make a bootable USB drive and use it? Then I suggest that you use of the the available tools with a graphical user interface that make the process relatively safe. -- Or do you want to learn the details and use a set of several basic [maybe command line] tools? Then the instructions by C.S.Cameron will be useful for you. -- Or do you want to create a custom iso file (in principle your own Linux distro)? That is much more advanced but possible, and there are several tutorials for that too.

Comment: As sudodus hinted, all that is needed for a USB drive that boots in UEFI mode is to copy the contents of the Ubuntu ISO to a FAT32 or NTFS partition. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 5):

### There are many ways to make a Bootable USB Flash Drive

**The following method extracts the contents of the ISO to a partition**

Making a Grub2 booter that uses Persistent partitions is easy.*

- Boot Installed Ubuntu or Live USB.
- Insert Target USB.
- Start GParted.
- Create a GPT partition table on Target USB.
- Create a 1MB BIOS boot partition on the left, formatted as unformatted.
- Add a 300MB FAT32 EFI boot partition next to it.
- Add an ext4 root partition large enough for the Ubuntu ISO's contents, (~ 3GB for 20.04).
- Create an ext4 partition labeled casper-rw
- Add a NTFS data partition if desired.
- Apply all operations.
- Flag partition 1 bios_grub.
- Flag Partition 2 boot, esp
- Close GParted.

[image: gparted]

- Open the ISO's folder as Administrator, open the ISO using Archive Manager.
- Extract the ISO's contents to the Target's root partition.
- Drag and drop the boot and EFI folders from Archive Manager window to the EFI boot partition.
- Edit sdx2/boot/grub/grub.cfg adding set root=(hd0,3) after the first line that starts with `menuentry`.
- Add a space and the word "persistent" after ---.

  ```
    set timeout=5
    menuentry "Ubuntu persistent" {
        set root=(hd0,3)
        set gfxpayload=keep
        linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --- persistent
        initrd  /casper/initrd
    }
  ```
- Install grub, if in BIOS mode or booted from USB drive run:

  ```
    sudo mount /dev/sdx2 /mnt

    sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdx
  ```
- If in UEFI mode on installed system, boot into the Target drive and run the above.

*Booting based on mkusb by sudodus

**Another method to make a bootable USB is to boot ISO files directly**

[BIOS/UEFI Template Image for Booting ISO Files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269462/bios-uefi-template-image-for-booting-iso-files)

Comment: I didn’t know this was possible. Excellent instructions. I’m bookmarking this for future reference.

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr** When you recreate the ISO from the extracted files, you are not (correctly) transferring either the BIOS bootblock, nor the EFI System Partition, or *ESP*, to the newly created USB drive. Therefore, the system will not be able to boot from this disk.

## Problem

### Loading the bootloader

The system firmware does not to know how to boot the operating system on the drive, and instead passes on that responsibility to a small program called the *bootloader*. It is stored on the disk in a specified location where the firmware can find it easily. The location where the bootloader is stored is dependent on the method used by the firmware to boot the disk. There are two different boot methods in use today on x86-64 platforms, the modern EFI and legacy BIOS boot.

I assume your HP Z-Book is new enough to be both x86-64, and support EFI boot. You will be able to enable legacy BIOS support in the system firmware's setup utility, though this may differ on other laptops, and could be subject to change for newer laptops.

#### EFI System Partition (ESP)

x86-64 EFI-based firmware loads the bootloader by looking for a file called `/efi/boot/bootx64.efi` (case does not matter) on a special, FAT32-formatted partition with type `0xEF` or `EFI System Partition (ESP)` on the selected boot disk. Some BIOSes can (apparently) also boot from NTFS file systems.

Most Linux distributions, Ubuntu included, now distribute an El Torrito-compliant disk image. This means the same disk can be booted by a legacy BIOS, or modern EFI-based firmware, in their respective boot modes. When you extract or mount the disk (i.e. from GNOME Files, the file manager), the EFI partition is maintained as a separate `efi.img` file, but this is actually *not* how the disk is arranged on a CD/DVD burned from this ISO file.

Therefore, the system firmware does not recognise this file as a valid EFI System Partition when it is copied to your USB drive. The drive is rejected by the firmware, because it does not believe the disk to be bootable.

## Resolving the problem

You can create an EFI System Partition using GNOME Disks, GParted, or command-line tools such as `gdisk`. The new partition must have the ESP type, and must be formatted as FAT32.

The contents of `efi.img` must be extracted to a folder called `efi` on the target disk, such that `bootx64.efi` appears at the path `/efi/boot/bootx64.efi` on the root of the disk.

The rest of the ISO may be extracted to the same partition, and this is what tools such as Rufus does. However, an extra step is often required for most Linux distributions: the file system label is often used to identify the disk from which to boot, and therefore, the file system's label must match that which came on the ISO file. Otherwise (with, for example, Ubuntu), the kernel will not be able to locate the SquashFS root file system to continue booting.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this very simple in Ubuntu 20 is:

Right click over your .iso file.
Open with other application.
Select Disk Image Writer
[image: Open with Disk Image Writer.]

When ask to restore Disk Image, select your USB target

[image: Restore ISO to USB]
Click on Start Restoring.

And that should be all!!.